# How to show smaller roads one zoom level later?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-studio

I am using Mapbox studio.
I use the default OSM road data.
If I zoom in at level 10 I only see major roads.
At zoom level 11 then suddenly lots of smaller roads appear.

I would like to show these roads at a later zoom level. I want to move everything one zoom level behind, so the small roads would show up at level 12.

How can I do that? I can not figure it out.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can change the layers' zoom extent. select or filter layers and move the "Select data" tab on the styling pannel.
Then, swipe the Min slider.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I have figured that one out already though. The problem is this will filter out all the roads and not just the smaller ones. How can I modify the zoom extent for  specific road classes within the road layer?

Comment: I realise I can filter classes, but I would rather adjust zoom levels for each class. If thats possible. Would I have to create layers for each class?

Comment: You can style by layer but features in the layer.